# Delete temp table for current spid

Tags: sql-server

How do I delete a temp table and ensure that its only for the current @@spid.

```
IF EXISTS
(
SELECT *
FROM tempdb.dbo.sysobjects
WHERE ID = OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#tmp')
)
BEGIN
DROP TABLE #tmp
END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A local #temp table is, by definition, only for the current <strike>spid</strike> `session_id` - so your query already does what you're asking. This is probably a bit simpler though:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#tmp', 'U') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  DROP TABLE #tmp;
END
```

But what is the purpose of explicitly dropping this temp table? You know the parser won't let you create another one with the same name in the same batch, right?

Comment: Its in a while loop and I'm searching for an item's last known price and telling customers that hey yeah this is the last known price for similiarly spelled items like 'Co%'.   Cola, Coast, Copper, Cobalt, Corn.  So I drop this intermediate table after collecting information about Cola and then start fresh again.  Seems logical when I wrote it, but I was afraid that by deleting the temp table if two or three sprocs fired at the same time it when cause strange side effects.

Comment: @RetroCoder why do you need a new temp table each time? Why do you need a temp table at all? I guess seeing the actual code might help provide a more optimal solution. What you're describing seems the opposite of optimal to me.

Comment: `CREATE PROCEDURE #tmp AS SELECT 1;` then run your above code. `Cannot use DROP TABLE with '#tmp' because '#tmp' is a procedure. Use DROP PROCEDURE.` Use second parameter 'U' of Object_ID.

Comment: @ErikE fair point, but do you know of anyone - on earth - who uses temporary procedures?

Comment: @Aaron I have used temporary procedures when I wasn't allowed to "modify" the database I was working with! Anyway, I am in the habit of specifying the object type since it's not always tables I'm checking for...

Comment: @ErikE and how many times have you had a #tmp procedure conflict in name with a #tmp table, in the same session? We're talking really edge case here.

Comment: @Aaron If there's an edge case that is easily eliminated, I eliminate it. Just like when I convert an int I always use `varchar(11)`. Someone argued with me about that, too, until one day it bit him. True, I suppose that if you really do have a naming conflict, you'll get a different error anyway when you try to create the temp table and it fails. But perhaps `There is already an object named '#tmp' in the database.` is a better description of what's going on.

Comment: @ErikE I get it, and I already incorporated your change. My point was that I've seen `DECLARE @x VARCHAR = '123'; SELECT @x;` fail silently far, far, far more often that I've ever seen anyone use a temporary procedure, never mind try to give a temporary procedure the same name as a temporary table. There's edge case and then there's edge of the universe case. YMMV.

Comment: Fair enough. Sorry to harass you about minuscule edge cases. There are certainly other, more important, issues.

Answer (score 2):

A local tempdb table (like `#tmp`) is only visible to the current session.

A global tempdb table (like `##tmp`) is also visible in other sessions.

As long as you use only a single `#` prefix, your temp tables will be local to your session.

For more information see this [article on SQL Server central](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/temporary-tables-in-sql-server/).

Comment: I realized that the #tmp table is used in the current session, but what I didn't realize is that I could only delete that temp table only in the current session and it was impossible to delete it a temp table in one session_id in another session_id.  Good to know though.

Comment: Ok.  You can always use `delete from #tmp` to empty a temporary table, it's not always necessary to delete it.

Comment: @Andomar just to be absolutely clear, you meant "to drop it" not "to delete it." I find the nomenclature absolutely confusing for newer users especially since when you right-click a table in Object Explorer and the drop action is called "delete." I think it's important to keep drop and delete as separate as possible.

Comment: I know the difference ... at work they suggest we use truncate instead of delete.  I wanted to use drop so I can prove to a contractor/consultant that #tmp is not a globally used temp table.  So I have more ammo now. thx