# Drop temp table if it exists

Tags: sql, sql-server

Friends,

I am creating a temp table. The script may be run several times so I need to check if the temp table exist then drop it. I have the written the code below but I get an error when running the script twice, that the table already exists:

**There is already an object named '#lu_sensor_name_19' in the database**.

It appears that `IF OBJECT_ID('alarm..#lu_sensor_name_19') IS NOT NULL` does not return true when the tablle is not null. What am I doing wrong?

```
IF OBJECT_ID('alarm..#lu_sensor_name_19') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN 
    DROP TABLE #lu_sensor_name_19 
END

CREATE TABLE #lu_sensor_name_19(
    sensorname_id int NOT NULL,
    sensorname nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    paneltype_id smallint NOT NULL,
    panel_version_id int NULL,
    prefix_allowed tinyint NOT NULL,
    base_allowed tinyint NOT NULL,
    suffix_allowed tinyint NOT NULL,
    key_value int NULL,
    sort_index int NULL,
    device_allowed tinyint NOT NULL,
    sensor_name_group_id smallint NOT NULL,
    )
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delete temp table for current spid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352801/delete-temp-table-for-current-spid)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Temp #Tables are created in tempdb.  Try this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#lu_sensor_name_19') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN 
    DROP TABLE #lu_sensor_name_19 
END

CREATE TABLE #lu_sensor_name_19...
```

SQL Server 2016 added the ability to do the drop in one line:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #lu_sensor_name_19 

CREATE TABLE #lu_sensor_name_19...
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.##myTempTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE ##myTempTable;
    --DROP TABLE ##tempdb.dbo.myTempTable;
    /* Above line commented out, because it generates warning:
    "Database name 'tempdb' ignored, referencing object in tempdb.",
    which is a pain in the neck if you are using a temp table to generate SQL code,
    and want to print the code to the screen.*/
END;
GO

CREATE TABLE ##myTempTable(
    FooBar nvarchar(128) not null,
);
```

And, in SQL Server 2016, you can write:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ##myTempTable
```

Comment: "##" does not work for me in SQL Server 2017. I need to write "tempdb..#" instead.

Comment: @MarJer ## is a global temp table.  # is a session-scoped temp table.  You can't use ## if you created a table with #, and vice versa. Also, ".." convention is tightly coupled to the executing user's default schema.  Use the actual schema instead. ".." is sloppy.  You should also NEVER use it in a stored procedure, because it will cause the engine to have to temporarily lock the system dictionaries to look up the current user's default schema. Always be explicit.